# Provisioning resource group and azure function at deployment level

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I've written up the script below to do the following:

- Provision a resource group
- In a separate deployment:

  - Provision a storage account
  - Provision a server farm
  - Provision a function app

The problem lies in the setting of the app settings in the function app, when I'm setting up the AzureWebJobsStorage. The resourceId function fails to resolve the storage account. When looking at the documention for the resourceId function, it states:

> When used with a subscription-level deployment, the resourceId() function can only retrieve the ID of resources deployed at that level. [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid)

But now I don't know how to resolve this!

Template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "functionName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "namingPrefix": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "resourceGroupLocation": "North Europe",
    "planName": "[replace(concat(variables('resourceGroupLocation'), 'Plan'),' ','')]",
    "resourceGroupName": "[concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), '-', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]",
    "functionName": "[concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), '-', parameters('functionName'))]",
    "storageAccName": "[toLower(concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), parameters('storageAccName')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
      "name": "[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
      "name": "NestedTemplate",
      "resourceGroup": "[variables('resourceGroupName')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('resourceGroupName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
              "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
              "name": "[variables('storageAccName')]",
              "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
              },
              "kind": "Storage",
              "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                  "bypass": "AzureServices",
                  "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                  "ipRules": [],
                  "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                  "services": {
                    "file": {
                      "enabled": true
                    },
                    "blob": {
                      "enabled": true
                    }
                  },
                  "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
              "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
              "name": "[variables('planName')]",
              "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
              "sku": {
                "name": "Y1",
                "tier": "Dynamic",
                "size": "Y1",
                "family": "Y",
                "capacity": 0
              },
              "kind": "functionapp",
              "properties": {
                "name": "[variables('planName')]",
                "computeMode": "Dynamic",
                "perSiteScaling": false,
                "reserved": false,
                "targetWorkerCount": 0,
                "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
              "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
              "name": "[variables('functionName')]",
              "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
              "dependsOn": [
                "[variables('planName')]",
                "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
                "[variables('storageAccName')]"
              ],
              "kind": "functionapp",
              "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
              },
              "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                  {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('functionName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "hostType": "Standard"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('functionName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "sslState": "Disabled",
                    "hostType": "Repository"
                  }
                ],
                "siteConfig": {
                  "appSettings": [
                    {
                      "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                      "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                      "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).key1)]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                      "value": "[variables('functionName')]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                      "value": "node"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                      "value": "10.14.1"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                      "value": "~2"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[variables('planName')]",
                "reserved": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Executed using following line:

```
New-AzDeployment -Location "North Europe" -TemplateFile $TemplateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $ParametersFilePath -namingPrefix $namingPrefix;
```

Output

```
 Resource Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts 'testStorageAccount' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/testStorageAccount' under resource group '<null>'
was not found."
  }
}'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue at a later date (probably myself) I was forced to create the resource group in my powershell script, and then use new-AzResourceGroupDeployment instead.

To accommodate this, the changes to the deployment template were minimal (I remove the resource group and brought the nested template one level up). However, I was also accessing the storage account key incorrectly. This has been updated in the code below.

```
$resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if(!$resourceGroup)
    {
        Write-Host "Creating resource group '$resourceGroupName' in location '$resourceGroupLocation'";
        New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $resourceGroupLocation
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Using existing resource group '$resourceGroupName'";
    }

    # Start the deployment
    Write-Host "Starting deployment...";
    if(Test-Path $parametersFilePath) {
        New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $TemplateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $parametersFilePath;
    }
```

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "functionName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "storageAccName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "namingPrefix": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "resourceGroupLocation": "North Europe",
    "planName": "[replace(concat(variables('resourceGroupLocation'), 'Plan'),' ','')]",
    "resourceGroupName": "[concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), '-', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]",
    "functionName": "[concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), '-', parameters('functionName'))]",
    "storageAccName": "[toLower(concat(parameters('namingPrefix'), parameters('storageAccName')))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccName')]",
      "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "virtualNetworkRules": [],
          "ipRules": [],
          "defaultAction": "Allow"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "encryption": {
          "services": {
            "file": {
              "enabled": true
            },
            "blob": {
              "enabled": true
            }
          },
          "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "name": "[variables('planName')]",
      "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y",
        "capacity": 0
      },
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('planName')]",
        "computeMode": "Dynamic",
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "reserved": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('functionName')]",
      "location": "[variables('resourceGroupLocation')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('planName')]",
        "[variables('appInsightsName')]",
        "[variables('storageAccName')]"
      ],
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "properties": {
        "enabled": true,
        "hostNameSslStates": [
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('functionName'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Standard"
          },
          {
            "name": "[concat(variables('functionName'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "sslState": "Disabled",
            "hostType": "Repository"
          }
        ],
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[variables('functionName')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "node"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "10.14.1"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~2"
            }
          ]
        },
        "serverFarmId": "[variables('planName')]",
        "reserved": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've run into a few "limitations" in the template language that make this hard at the moment (we're working on improving both).

1) *Inline* nested deployments have the scope of the top-level deployment when evaluating template language expressions (anything in []) which is sometimes convenient (you can share variables for example) but more often than not causes some problem (like the resourceId function).  ARM has always behaved this way but with the advent of subscription level deployments it's a bit more problematic (you run into it more).  To get around this you can use linked templates - I know that's not always ideal but they will behave as expected.

2) the second thing you're running into is that list*() functions are evaluated immediately if ARM thinks the resource you're accessing is not within the same deployment.  Due to #1, that's what ARM thinks in this case and why trying to concat() the resourceID still doesn't work.

Aside from that, stay away from the providers() function for apiVersions, it's not deterministic and the results of that function can change without you knowing it.  The code you had in your original post for listKeys did work a while back and you might see it in samples floating around, but changes in the platform can break that function's behavior.  Literal apiVersions are always better in ARM templates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, nesting in line probably wasn't the smartest thing, but i was just trying to get it to work! I agree about the providers() function. Was merely testing it out. Have been bitten one too many times by getting the latest in NPM!

Comment: Honestly, nesting is a great idea, it's just broken for anything beyond hello world scenarios - will hopefully get that fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

The docs are confusing and don't describe how `resourceId()` works at that level. It should really say:

> When used in a subscription level deployment `resourceId()` can only get the resource IDs of resource groups (`Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups`), policies (`Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments`), and role definitions (`Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions`), as these are subscription level specific resources.

Since that's how it actually works. [More docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/deploy-to-subscription#use-template-functions).

In terms of how to proceed from here, you'll simply need to deploy the resource groups in one template at the subscription level, and the resources in another template at the resource group level.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I've considered having a subscription level deployment and then another with resource level. But I was hoping to keep everything in a single timplate file, so only one deployment needs to be executed. Do you mean that this is impossible

Comment: I've been trying to get it working for the past hour or so, and I don't think it can be done because `listKeys` ultimately requires some usage of the resource ID of the storage account. For your reference, I tried manually constructing the storage account ID using `[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', variables('resourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccName'))]` and using it in `listKeys` since this is what `resourceId()` returns, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yep! Tried that as well! Shame. Thanks for taking the time to try it out.

Comment: I've also been struggling with this for a good number of  hours, determined that there MUST be a way.  But I do not think there is a way.  I can only get listKeys to work by manually constructing the resource identifier, and by doing so the template has no knowledge of making an implicit dependency.  And, oh, it doesn't seem to matter WHAT you put in dependsOn.  Those resources are not respected.  And, oh, it doesn't seem to matter how you NEST your resources either.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue and found that they more recently support nested templates better by defining inner and outer scopes on the deployment resources and function scopes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/cross-scope-deployment?tabs=azure-cli#how-functions-resolve-in-scopes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96XxVyxrhZI

Answer (score -2):

Edited -

Sorry I jumped the gun earlier, the issue is with New-AzDeployment which is specifically for deploying subscription level resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azdeployment?view=azps-2.7.0

Excerpts from the link above -

> The New-AzDeployment cmdlet adds a deployment at the current
>   subscription scope. This includes the resources that the deployment
>   requires.
>
> An Azure resource is a user-managed Azure entity. A resource can live
>   in a resource group, like database server, database, website, virtual
>   machine, or Storage account. Or, it can be a subscription level
>   resource, like role definition, policy definition, etc.
>
> To add resources to a resource group, use the
>   New-AzResourceGroupDeployment which creates a deployment at a resource
>   group. The New-AzDeployment cmdlet creates a deployment at the current
>   subscription scope, which deploys subscription level resources.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately this shouldn't be is issue. I have the storage account marked as a dependency, and both are in the same resource group